# How can you return a new valid page object with WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, pageobjects, webdriver-io

We have just started implementing a WebdriverIO-mocha-chai framework at work and since I have a Selenium/Java background, it's a little tricky for me to wrap my head around it.

My page objects look like this:

```
**page.js**

export default class Page {

  get title() { return browser.getTitle() };
  get header() { return browser.element('.Header') }
  get logoutLink() { return browser.element('a.logout') }


  open(url) {
    browser.windowHandleFullscreen().url(`/#/${url}`);
  }
}


**page1.js**

import Page from './page'
import Page2 from './Page2'

class Page1 extends Page {

  get element1() { return browser.element('selector1') }
  get element2() { return browser.element('selector2') }

  clickElement1Page1() {
    this.element1.scroll();
    this.element1.waitForVisible();
    this.element1.click();
    return this;
  }
}

export default new Page1()

**page2.js**

import Page from './page'
import Page1 from './page1';

class Page2 extends Page {
  get element1() { return browser.element('selector1') }
  get element2() { return browser.element('selector2') }
  get element3() { return browser.element('selector3') }
  get element4() { return browser.element('selector4') }

  open() {
    super.open('page2')
  }

  clickElement1Page2() {
    this.element1.scroll();
    this.element1.waitForVisible();
    this.element1.click();
    return this;
  }

  fillForm(name, title) {
    this.element2.setValue(name);
    this.element3.setValue(title);
    this.element4.click();
    return new Page1();
  }
}

export default new Page2()
```

The difference between this and the advised model on the WebdriverIO site is that I added the return statements, which brings us to the issue I need help with. I want my tests to look as simple as possible, like:

```
Page2.clickElement1Page2().fillForm("text", "text").clickElement1Page1();

expect(...).to.be.true;
```

Right now I'm getting a "_page1.default is not a constructor" at line `return new Page1()`.

Taking into account that in this paradigm the elements are not initialised in the constructor, is this kind of chaining possible with WebdriverIO?
Any suggestions or examples of a solid webdriverIO POM project are highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you'll be able to accomplish what you're wanting to do via changing `return new Page1()` to `return Page1`.

That said -- I don't believe the benefit of returning `Page1` from within `Page2` is worth it though.  In my opinion, page objects are useful because you can clearly separate pages/sections of your application, including in your test cases.  I would certainly recommend using `return this` to be able to chain commands within individual page objects, though.

Writing

```
Page2.clickElement1Page2().fillForm("text", "text")
Page1.clickElement1Page1()
```

Clearly signifies that page navigation is expected, and that you're now on Page1.  Debugging is a lot easier as well, because you can go directly to Page1 rather than potentially having to follow a long chain from other Pages.